# Using Spring Data Rest RepositoryEntityLinks outside of Controller

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I would like to use the RepositoryEntityLinks class to get the link to a resource at various places in my code as per section 12.1 of the current Spring Data Rest manual

> 12.1. Programmatic Links Sometimes you need to add links to exported resources **in your own custom built Spring MVC controller**s. There are
>   three basic levels of linking available:
>
> ...
>
> 3 Using Spring Data REST’s implementation of RepositoryEntityLinks.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_programmatic_links

I note the docs refer explicitly to "...your own custom built Spring MVC controllers" and it would seem that is the only place it is available. I would like to use the configured instance in a Spring Security AuthenticationSuccessHandler however the application fails to start with the error:

No qualifying bean of type[org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks] found

I have been able to successfully inject it to a controller as expected.

Can I use the RepositoryEntityLinks class outside of a Spring MVC Controller?

```
public class RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
  @Autowired
  private RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks;

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    //do something with entityLinks
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. I have successfully used it in Assembler which generates links from HATEOAS model. Altough there may be some restrictions on where `RepositoryEntityLinks` class can be injected, for sure it can be used outside of Controllers.

Below you can see my working example. If anyone wnders this class extends [ResourceAssemblerSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ResourceAssemblerSupport.html) which is part of `spring-hateoas` module. Maybe that's the thing that enables injection here.

```java
@Component
public class UserAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<UserEntity, UserResource> {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryEntityLinks repositoryEntityLinks;

    public UserAssembler() {
        super(UserController.class, UserResource.class);
    }

    @Override
    public UserResource toResource(UserEntity userEntity) {
        Link userLink = repositoryEntityLinks.linkToSingleResource(UserEntity.class, userEntity.getId());
        Link self = new Link(entryLink.getHref(), Link.REL_SELF);
        return new UserResource(userEntity, self);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, though it appears that RepositoryEntityLinks only works within the scope of a REST request.  If you're writing any code that interacts with the Java repository interfaces directly (e.g., interface a `PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<...>`), then RepositoryEntityLinks dies with an IllegalStateException ("No current ServletRequestAttributes"), since it tries to construct the URI using `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentServletMapping()`. Have you been able to use it outside of an HTTP request scope?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class RestApiIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryEntityLinks repositoryEntityLinks;

    @BeforeEach
    public void initServletRequestAttributes() {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
    }

    @Test
    void test() { 
        System.out.println(repositoryEntityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(SomeClass.class));
    }

}
```

The code is based on [spring-data-rest-tests-core](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/tree/main/spring-data-rest-tests/spring-data-rest-tests-core): [AbstractControllerIntegrationTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/main/spring-data-rest-tests/spring-data-rest-tests-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/rest/tests/AbstractControllerIntegrationTests.java), [TestMvcClient](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/main/spring-data-rest-tests/spring-data-rest-tests-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/rest/tests/TestMvcClient.java).